# Does Django differentiate btw jpg and png files when processing static files?

Tags: django, static

Does Django differentiate between `jpg` and `png` files when processing static files? Specifically, when a `jpg` file is in the `static` directory (vs. in the `static/media` directory)?

In my case: the `jpg` image doesn't load in `<img src="{% static 'weather.jpg' %}" alt="">`, but the `png` image does in the same url: `<img src="{% static 'doggie.png' %}" alt="">`.

But both the `png` and `jpg` images load if they are in the `static/media` directory--which led me to wonder whether `jpg` files must be in a `media` folder:

`<img src="{% static 'media/doggie3.png' %}" alt="">` and `<img src="{% static 'media/weather.jpg' %}" alt="">`

Here's how 'static' is setup in `settings.py` file (ok: I admit The code is cobbled together, but at least one type of static file is loading):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = Path.joinpath(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL ='/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = Path.joinpath(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

And in `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns += [
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    ... 
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

File tree:

```
local_library_tutorial
    catalog
        admin.py
        apps.py
        media
        migrations
        models.py
        static
        templates
        tests.py
        urls.py
        views.py
    db.sqlite3
    locallibrary
        __init__.py
        __pycache__
        asgi.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    manage.py
    misc.txt
    requirements.txt
    seed_data.json
    static
    venv
```

Comment: Please add your filetree to the question.

Comment: Couldn't format it well in comment, so amended it in my original post

Comment: For testing purposes, I copied both files into various directories I was testing. And in my template, I liked to all of them--to figure out what worked and what didn't. That's how I realized the jpg file only showed up in the `media` folder.

Comment: You don't have a media directory in `local_library_tutorial` though? The static directory and media directory are different things. static files are files that won't change like CSS, JS, images, whereas media files are user uploaded files.

Comment: Why would media and static be the same thing? Media is where uploaded files reside (by the user/visitor, such as avatars, gallery images, etc). Static is where files reside that are part of the code (reside in the repository, such as css/js files and small graphics, logo of the site, etc).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat There is a media directory inside the `static` directory. Perhaps I'm missing something--*regardless* of which directory, when the directories are working, the png image displays, but the jpg image doesn't.

Comment: @Melvyn I understand what you are saying, but for me, the png image and the jpg image seem to work differently, *regardless* of which directory.

Comment: They don't. They really, 100% don't. So look into other causes. If you reference the "static/media" directory, you aren't even using the MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL settings, so there is nothing magic about .jpg or a directory named "media". Either you're making the same typo over and over, so that it seems the jpg file is missing or you're hitting browser cache, or something we can't see.

Comment: @Melvyn Thanks! I'll stop fixating on the jpg/png thing. It's entirely possible there is a minor typo--happened many times.